# Convert address to longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, django, cocoa-touch, ios5

I want to do the following
- Allow users to input a physical address in ios app.
- This address is converted to longitude/latitude 
- Django server code checks to see nearby locations.

How can I do this most efficiently?

Should I convert the address to longitude and latitude in ios app and then send the coordinates to django server code, or should I send the address to django server code and then covert address to longitude and latitude?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) - it enables you to do geo spatial lookups... For converting the address to coordinates you will most like need an external API.

Comment: I'm using this javascript and it works just fine: https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/#populate-form-data

Answer (score 5):

According to the Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html) You can achieve this using a CLGeocoder object:

```
CLGeocoder* geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Your Address"
     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
         {
         // Process the placemark.
         }
}];
```

A CLPlacemark object has a property called location that yields latitude and longitude for the place.

Comment: Keep in mind that `CLGeocoder` was added in iOS 5.0 and this question has been tagged with 4.0. This solution will not work under iOS 4.x.

Comment: My bad, i hadn't noticed the tag! I just would expect the author to point out this need in the question itself tho.

Comment: That's OK, there is really no need to support iOS 4 anymore anyway.

Comment: It's fine. IOS 5.0 was what I meant anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to get `(latitude, longitude)` tuple on the django side

```
import urllib, urllib2
import simplejson as json

def getLatLng( address ):
    """ Native address format is House Number, Street Direction, Street Name, 
    Street Suffix, City, State, Zip, Country """

    TIMEOUT = 3

    try:
        url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + urllib.quote_plus( address.encode('utf-8') ) + "&sensor=false"
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        req = urllib2.Request( url )

        data = json.load( opener.open(req, None, TIMEOUT) )
        results = data['results']
        if len( results ):
            location = results[0]['geometry']['location']
            return  ( location['lat'], location['lng'] )
        else:
            return None
    except:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link,this will return json which consist of latitude and longitude for the physical address.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Newyork&sensor=false